# How do I listen for a specific next-protocol with ALPN negotation in twisted?

Tags: twisted

In TLS it is possible to negotiate a next-protocol using [ALPN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301), originally created to deal with HTTP/2. It would be nice to be able to register multiple listeners for different next-protocols. How do I do that in twisted? Is there a `twist` command line syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a generic ALPN dispatcher. [twisted/web/http.py chooses protocols based on NPN/ALPN here](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/web/http.py#L2885) and the documentation has [an example of using ALPN](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html#application-layer-protocol-negotiation-alpn-and-next-protocol-negotiation-npn).